# pipelinedb continuous views do not work

Tags: postgresql, pipelinedb

First I go and create stream:

```
CREATE STREAM raw_searches_total
(
  stamp text,
  searches integer
);
```

I see:

```
CREATE STREAM
```

Fine. Then I create continuous view as follows:

```
CREATE CONTINUOUS VIEW searches_total_10min AS
SELECT
  substring(stamp from 0 for 16) || '0:00' AS stamp,
  sum(searches) AS searches
FROM raw_searches_total GROUP BY stamp;
```

Pipeline shows me:

```
CREATE CONTINUOUS VIEW
```

I interpret that as "OK" and go ahead, I try to manually insert data into my stream:

```
INSERT INTO raw_searches_total (stamp, searches) VALUES ('2015-08-26 21:00:00', 200);
```

It gives me:

```
INSERT 0 1
```

I google what does that mean and find out that 0 is some kind of ID and 1 is actual count of how many rows were inserted. Okay, fine, then I finally query my continuous view:

```
SELECT * FROM searches_total_10min;
```

And suddenly I get:

```
 stamp | searches
-------+----------
(0 rows)
```

So, the question is: **where is my data?**

To my surprise, this will be the first ever question on stackoverflow with `pipelinedb` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I'm one of the PipelineDB engineers and I do indeed apologize for the hangup here. It appears that the problem is the result of using one of  `raw_searches_total`'s column names as an alias within your the continuous view. In particular, `stamp` is used several times and we admittedly aren't handling that redundancy as well as we should be.

Can you try aliasing the continuous view's column with something more unique? e.g.:

```
CREATE CONTINUOUS VIEW searches_total_10min AS
SELECT
  substring(stamp from 0 for 16) || '0:00' AS truncated_stamp,
  sum(searches) AS searches
FROM raw_searches_total GROUP BY truncated_stamp;
```